# Deleting and applying firewall rules in powershell painfully slow

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall

I have several scripts containing `New-NetFirewallRule` commandlets, in total there are about 200 rules, and to delete existing rules and then apply new ones it takes about 15 minutes.

According to documentation `New-NetFirewallRule` cmdlet has `GPOSession` paramter which lets you specify GPO object, the GPO is loaded using `Open-NetGPO`, you do modifications and then save the GPO back.

However it's useless parameter since it looks like this only works for domains, I'm on Windows 10 single computer network, no domain.

Obviously each `New-NetFirewallRule` cmdlet is called independently against localhost GPO, which is too slow, is there a way to load local group policy somehow, do what you want, and then apply changes back without accessing the GPO for each firewall rule?

**EDIT:**
To respond on comment I think all the rules are simple enough, ie. not dealing with heavy calls, like this: (there are 200+ such rules)

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Confirm:$Execute -Whatif:$Debug -ErrorAction $OnError -Platform $Platform `
-DisplayName "Multicast Domain Name System" -Service Dnscache -Program $ServiceHost `
-PolicyStore $PolicyStore -Enabled True -Action Allow -Group $Group -Profile Private, Domain -InterfaceType $Interface `
-Direction $Direction -Protocol UDP -LocalAddress Any -RemoteAddress 224.0.0.251 -LocalPort 5353 -RemotePort 5353 `
-LocalUser Any -LocalOnlyMapping $false -LooseSourceMapping $false `
-Description "In computer networking, the multicast DNS (mDNS) protocol resolves hostnames to IP addresses
within small networks that do not include a local name server."
```

A lot of variables are predefined, but only a few variables use more complex call but this happens only once during initialization of a script.

for example to figure out loopback interface alias:

```
$Loopback = Get-NetIPInterface | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceAlias -like "*Loopback*" -and $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceAlias
```

To delete rules, I use this command, which deletes a group of rules:

```
Remove-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore $PolicyStore -Group $Group -Direction $Direction -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Can you give examples of what you've tried?

Comment: Sorry I haven't try anything, because there are no options available for home computers.

Comment: I mean, what are some example powershell commands you've tried to add and delete firewall rules, that take so long?

Comment: I mean, using where-object with every rule instead of the get-netfirewall*filter commands would be much slower.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean, I've updated my question, but it's unlikely that few calls which are initalized during startup could case problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could user *Local Security Policy* tool (`secpol.msc`) to make your configuration and export it to an `.inf` file. Then on the target machine either use the same tool to import the `.inf` or `secedit.exe` for scripting: (if the file exported was `mypolicy.inf`)

```
secedit /configure /db %windir%\security\local.sdb /cfg mypolicy.inf
```

Comment: That's new for me, I was hoping for something simple, thank you for solution.